# Winget renamed Microsoft.Teams into Microsoft.Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-teams, winget

I was experimenting with `winget`, looking what Windows components I could easily remove with its help.

I ran `winget install --id Microsoft.Teams`, and then uninstalled it with `winget uninstall --id Microsoft.Teams`.

This seemingly removed the package, but something got wrong and in the list of all packages in the system I see that Teams got renamed into Microsoft Edge. I tried uninstalling Microsoft Teams, but it doesn't allow me to do that, because it thinks it's Microsoft Edge. I tried uninstalling Edge, but that did not work either.

How can I possibly rename the package back from Microsoft Edge into Microsoft Teams so that the name matches the ID?

[image]

Comment: Try `winget uninstall -id Microsoft.Teams`

Comment: I did that too - it says package not found.

Comment: If System Restore is enabled, rollback to before this happened.